# Why concatenate features in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning

I am learning Microsoft ML framework and confused why features need to be concatenated. In Iris flower example from Microsoft here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/iris-clustering

... features are concatenated:

```
string featuresColumnName = "Features";
var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms
    .Concatenate(featuresColumnName, "SepalLength", "SepalWidth", "PetalLength", "PetalWidth")
    ...
```

Are multiple features treated as a single feature in order to do calculations like linear regression? If so, how is this accurate? What is happening behind the scenes?

Comment: the columns contains value for all the records you need to deal with. concatenation makes the data from columns to a table which you can view each row as a record. And the record is the data point you need to do cluster or regression with.

Comment: Would it processing a combined data point be less accurate than processing multiple independent points? What if one of the columns (features) was only slightly helpful at predicting the outcome. By combining it with other features, are you not giving it equal weight to other features?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.transformextensionscatalog.concatenate?view=ml-dotnet),

> concatenation is necessary because trainers take feature vectors as
> inputs.

It essentially transforms the features in the form of separate columns into a single column of feature vectors. Feature values themselves remain intact; only their format and type is changed. It is more clear through this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.transformextensionscatalog.concatenate?view=ml-dotnet):

Before transformation:

```
        var samples = new List<InputData>()
        {
            new InputData(){ Feature1 = 0.1f, Feature2 = new[]{ 1.1f, 2.1f,
                3.1f }, Feature3 = 1 },

            new InputData(){ Feature1 = 0.2f, Feature2 = new[]{ 1.2f, 2.2f,
                3.2f }, Feature3 = 2 },

            new InputData(){ Feature1 = 0.3f, Feature2 = new[]{ 1.3f, 2.3f,
                3.3f }, Feature3 = 3 },

            new InputData(){ Feature1 = 0.4f, Feature2 = new[]{ 1.4f, 2.4f,
                3.4f }, Feature3 = 4 },

            new InputData(){ Feature1 = 0.5f, Feature2 = new[]{ 1.5f, 2.5f,
                3.5f }, Feature3 = 5 },

            new InputData(){ Feature1 = 0.6f, Feature2 = new[]{ 1.6f, 2.6f,
                3.6f }, Feature3 = 6 },
        };
```

After:

```
    //  "Features" column obtained post-transformation.
    //  0.1 1.1 2.1 3.1 1
    //  0.2 1.2 2.2 3.2 2
    //  0.3 1.3 2.3 3.3 3
    //  0.4 1.4 2.4 3.4 4
    //  0.5 1.5 2.5 3.5 5
    //  0.6 1.6 2.6 3.6 6
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the OPs comment?  Should the data be concatenated in the pre-training data prep step or should distinct pieces of data or columns remain separate?  Does it matter?